# Improve performance in Hiding columns of table

Tags: jquery, html

I am doing hiding of columns while clicking on it's header. My table has column span and also rowspan. Code what i am using is

```
selector = " > tbody > tr:has(td) td:nth-child(" + Ix + ")";

$(tbl).find(selector).each(function () {

    if (rIx > 0) {
            HideAndShowEle($(this)[0], bShow, true);
    }

})
```

Hiding for big tables which has more than 200 rows and 20 columns are very slow. Help me to find any other way to select particular columns td in better way

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on the header hides the column.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/S8Ntz/1/)

```
$("table thead th").on("click", function(){
   var index = $(this).index() + 1; 
    $("table tr td:nth-child(" + index + ")").add(this).hide()
});​



<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Head 1</th>
            <th>Head 2</th>
            <th>Head 3</th>
            <th>Head 4</th>
            <th>Head 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
selector = $('table tbody').has('td').children(Ix)
```

$(selector).each(function () {

```
if (rIx > 0) {
        HideAndShowEle($(this)[0], bShow, true);
}
```

})

Answer (score 0):

My preferred technique for columns (assuming you have no cells which have multiple column spans) is to use a unique css class for each column and simply use that class as its selector. It doesn't have to correspond to an actual css class, it just has to be identifiable.

```
<table class="firstTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="column1"></td>
    <td class="column2"></td>
    <td class="column3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="column1"></td>
    <td class="column2"></td>
    <td class="column3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="secondTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="column1"></td>
    <td class="column2"></td>
    <td class="column3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="column1"></td>
    <td class="column2"></td>
    <td class="column3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now using the common selectors you can hide a column:

```
$(".firstTable .column2").hide();
```

To get to this from a link in the header, you can provide a data attribute to the link to indicate which column it's in or use it's parent.

```
<a href="#" data-column="column2" data-table="firstTable" class="columnHeader">Column Header</a>

$(".columnHeader").click(function(event) {
    var col = $(this).attr("column");
    var table = $(this).attr("table");
    $("." + table + " ." + col).hide();
});
```

There are obvious holes in this posted code mostly because I don't know your specific requirements or page structures, but the concepts here should be fairly adaptable.